# Gson with generics - how to get an object with inner generic member

Tags: java, json, generics, gson

Let's say I have the following entities

```
public class City {
   public int id;
   public String name;
}

public class State<T> {
   public int id;
   public String name;

   public T capital;
}
```

**Where I dont know anything about the type of capital.**
And now I create both object and call toJson and fromJson as follows:

```
City capital = new City(1, "1");
State state = new State<City>(1, "1", capital);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(state);
State fromJsonState = gson.fromJson(json, State.class);
```

My returned object of the from method is

[image]

where everything is typed but capital (generic).
How can I get the same object after the json serialize & desirialize?

Answer (score 0):

Use parametrized [TypeToken](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/reflect/TypeToken.html) to construct the Type and use [Gson#fromJson(String,Type)](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.reflect.Type%29).

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(state);
Type type = new TypeToken<State<City>>() {}.getType();
State<City> fromJsonState = gson.fromJson(json, type); 

System.out.println(fromJsonState.capital.getClass().getName());
```

output:

```
com.x.y.z.City
```